# publish on fan page with wordpress plugin

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Setting the Facebook plugin for WordPress, the "enable" option does not show up.  How can I solve it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To enabled this option you need to have page on your facebook account. When you have page on your account you will see those on this list.